# Determining whether or not the following collection of vectors ${\rm I\!R}^4$ are a subspace of ${\rm I\!R}^4$

Tags: vectors

There is the following list of vectors, and my thoughts are these;

[image]

a) This is a subspace because every single vector would be linearly independent. 
b) These vectors would not be because $v_3$ is less than $v_2$, therefore not equal and not a subspace of ${\rm I\!R}^4$ 
c) This would be a subspace because the first two vectors minus the second two should equal $0$

Comment: Do you know what you need to check to see if a subset of a vector space is a subspace?

Comment: I do not, I thought I was doing the correct process?

Comment: Well, after I commented, two different people answered with what you need to check. One gave a single condition, and the other broke it down into three conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of a linear subspace: if $v,w$ are in the set, is $\alpha v + \beta w$ in the set for any scalars $\alpha,\beta$?

For each subpart, either prove this is true, or find a counterexample.

For example: for part (a), consider as a counterexample:

- $v = (1,0,0,0)$
- $w=(0,1,0,0)$
- $\alpha=1$
- $\beta=1$.

Each of $v,w$ is in the
set, but

$$1 \cdot v + 1\cdot w = (1,1,0,0)$$
and $1 + 1+ 0 + 0 \neq 1.$ So the set in part (a) is not a linear subspace.

Comment: This would also be true for part (c) correct?

Comment: @overlord12 Part (c) is actually true---the 0 instead of a 1 on the RHS makes a huge difference. See if you can prove why.

Answer (score 0):

Use the characterization of subspace.

Let $V$ a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$, given a set $W$ such that $W\subset V$ then $W$ is a subspace of $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$ if the following conditions Holds:

$1.0_v\in W$

$2 \forall u,v\in W ,\, u+v\in W$

$3.\forall k\in \mathbb{F} \, \text{and}\,  v\in W$ $kv\in W$

Comment: Could you explain this a tad bit more?

Comment: 1) says that the zero vector needs to be in the set. (2) says that the sum of any two vectors in the set needs to be in the set. (3) says that any scalar times any vector in the set needs to be in the set (with the scalar equal to zero, this implies 1)